# Using Celery with SQLAlchemy and Pyramid

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, celery, pyramid

I'm creating the web app using Pyramid-1.2.1 with SQLAlchemy as database backend.
Now I need to do some periodic tasks along with this app and I want to use Celery as a task processor and SQLAlchemy as the message queue and the result backend.

1) I've installed Celery-2.1.4 but I can not figure out how to make it work. Here is my `celeryconfig.py` file:

```
# List of modules to import when celery starts.
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("my_app.tasks", )

## Result store settings.
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "database"
CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = "sqlite:///MyDataBase.db"
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = "json"

## Broker settings.
BROKER_TRANSPORT = "sqlakombu.transport.Transport"
BROKER_HOST = "sqlite:///MyDataBase.db"
```

The `my_app.tasks` contain a simple addition task from the celery examples.
Now when I run

```
$ celeryd -l info
```

I see the following:

```
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,750: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@OrangeMac.local v2.1.4 is starting.
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,765: WARNING/MainProcess]  
Configuration ->
    . broker -> sqlakombu.transport.Transport://guest@sqlite:///MyDataBase.db/
    . queues ->
        . celery -> exchange:celery (direct) binding:celery
    . concurrency -> 4
    . loader -> celery.loaders.default.Loader
    . logfile -> [stderr]@INFO
    . events -> OFF
    . beat -> OFF
    . tasks ->
        . chatrooms.task.add
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,787: INFO/PoolWorker-1] child process calling self.run()
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,789: INFO/PoolWorker-2] child process calling self.run()
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,791: INFO/PoolWorker-3] child process calling self.run()
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,796: INFO/PoolWorker-4] child process calling self.run()
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,802: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@OrangeMac.local has started.
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,804: WARNING/MainProcess] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,805: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Users/shashkin/python_v_env/bin/celeryd", line 8, in <module>
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,805: WARNING/MainProcess] load_entry_point('celery==2.1.4', 'console_scripts', 'celeryd')()
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,805: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Users/shashkin/python_v_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/celeryd.py", line 166, in main
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,805: WARNING/MainProcess] worker.execute_from_commandline()
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,806: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Users/shashkin/python_v_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/base.py", line 40, in execute_from_commandline
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,806: WARNING/MainProcess] return self.run(*args, **vars(options))
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,806: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Users/shashkin/python_v_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/celeryd.py", line 85, in run
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,806: WARNING/MainProcess] return Worker(**kwargs).run()
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,806: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Users/shashkin/python_v_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.7.egg/celery/apps/worker.py", line 121, in run
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,807: WARNING/MainProcess] self.run_worker()
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,807: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Users/shashkin/python_v_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.7.egg/celery/apps/worker.py", line 219, in run_worker
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,807: WARNING/MainProcess] worker.start()
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,807: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Users/shashkin/python_v_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 217, in start
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,808: WARNING/MainProcess] component.start()
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,808: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Users/shashkin/python_v_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/listener.py", line 238, in start
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,808: WARNING/MainProcess] self.reset_connection()
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,808: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Users/shashkin/python_v_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/listener.py", line 416, in reset_connection
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,808: WARNING/MainProcess] self.connection = self._open_connection()
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,808: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Users/shashkin/python_v_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/listener.py", line 480, in _open_connection
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,809: WARNING/MainProcess] max_retries=conf.BROKER_CONNECTION_MAX_RETRIES)
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,809: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Users/shashkin/python_v_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.7.egg/celery/utils/__init__.py", line 276, in retry_over_time
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,809: WARNING/MainProcess] retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,809: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Users/shashkin/python_v_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/listener.py", line 472, in _establish_connection
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,809: WARNING/MainProcess] conn.connect()                              # evaluate connection
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,809: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Users/shashkin/python_v_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/carrot-0.10.7-py2.7.egg/carrot/connection.py", line 170, in connect
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,810: WARNING/MainProcess] return self.connection
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,810: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Users/shashkin/python_v_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/carrot-0.10.7-py2.7.egg/carrot/connection.py", line 135, in connection
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,810: WARNING/MainProcess] self._connection = self._establish_connection()
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,810: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Users/shashkin/python_v_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/carrot-0.10.7-py2.7.egg/carrot/connection.py", line 148, in _establish_connection
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,810: WARNING/MainProcess] return self.create_backend().establish_connection()
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,810: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Users/shashkin/python_v_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/carrot-0.10.7-py2.7.egg/carrot/connection.py", line 161, in create_backend
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,810: WARNING/MainProcess] return backend_cls(connection=self)
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,811: WARNING/MainProcess] TypeError
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,811: WARNING/MainProcess] :
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,811: WARNING/MainProcess] __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
[2011-11-11 20:22:50,811: INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
```

What am I missing?

2) Later I want to start Celery inside my app. What should I do after celery-pylons package installation? Should I put celery's settings in app's `.ini` file? Could someone provide me any example, because those I found in the net did not help me much.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm no Celery expert but it seems like you're providing a custom backend to _carrot_, and the signature of the `__init__` method of your custom transport class is wrong.

Comment: Does the database exist? If not did you try creating it, can you establish a connection to the database using
>>> myconn = BrokerConnection("sqlite:///MyDataBase.db", transport="sqlakombu.transport.Transport")

Comment: You should create 2 different SO questions. I think it's easier to reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like an issue with version compatibility between `celery` packages and its dependencies. With the latest version of celery, 2.4.5 your example just works. With 2.1.4 I get the same error.

If for any reason you need 2.1.4 version of celery only, you have to find out which dependencies you need to downgrade in order to make it work. By looking at the traceback, most likely, it'll be the carrot `dependency` but you may get into a dependency hell if other dependencies need certain version of `carrot`.

I strongly suggest to use virtualenv with pip to be able to experiment with the versions of the packages easily. Trying to develop something using Python packages from Linux repositories can be very painful.

[buildout versions](http://packages.python.org/buildout-versions/use.html) or [pip requirements](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html) address this kind of problems but AFAIK there is no set of pinned dependency versions for celery.

Comment: Actually I postponed this task so I did not full testing now, but I tried at least start `celeryd` and looks like it works with v2.4. Moreover, my stupid fault was that I was confused with versions 2.1.4 and 2.4.1 (the latest on that moment) and chose the wrong one. Thanks again for opening my eyes! :)